# redireccionar a una pagina en PHP con header

Tags: php

**Buen Día.**

Tengo un script el cual luego de que un usuario inicia sesión lo envía al panel de control de su cuenta mediante un enlace al que hay que que dar clic, todo funciona de maravilla, pero pienso que seria mejor que automáticamente se redirija al panel de control y así no tener que dar clic en mencionado enlace, el problema es que no redirige con header, sale el siguiente error

> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by
>   (output started at
>   /home2/gabriel/tecflucol.com/sistema/PHP/checklogin.php:4) in
>   /home2/softwareiii.com/sistema/PHP/checklogin.php on line 26

como podria hacerle para solucionarle y que rediriga a la pagina automaticamente?

***Aqui el codigo:***

```
<?php
    session_start();
?>

<?php
    include('../PHP/conectar.php');

    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `usuarios` WHERE `usuario`='$username';";
    $result = $conexion->query($sql);

    if ($result->num_rows > 0)
    {
        $row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    }

    if (password_verify($password, $row['contrasena']))
    {
        $_SESSION['loggedin'] = true;
        $_SESSION['usuario'] = $username;
        $_SESSION['start'] = time();
        $_SESSION['expire'] = $_SESSION['start'] + (5 * 800000);

        //rediriguir automanticamente
        header('Location: panel_de_control.php');

        //estas dos lineas funcionan bien pero la idea es suprimirlas
        //echo "Bienvenido(a)! ".$_SESSION['usuario'];
        //echo "<br><br><a href=panel_de_control.php>PANEL DE CONTROL</a>";
    }
    else
    {
      echo "Usuario o contraseña estan incorrectos.";
      echo "<br><a href='../login.html'>Volver a Intentarlo</a>";
    }
     mysqli_close($conexion);
?>
```

Comment: Hola, ¿cual es la linea 26 de tu checklogin.php? ¿El código que has compartido esta dentro de tu checklogin.php o de otro fichero?

Comment: es la linea donde esta el header('Location: panel_de_control.php'); el codigo que muestro es el checklogin.php

Comment: Prueba borrando `?>` y `<?php` que están después de `session_start();` Es decir, solo deja el `<?php` del principio y el `?>` del final.

Comment: @Ferni Gracias mi hermano!! la verdad no se por que exactamente al quitar eso se soluciono el problema, lo importante es que sirva.. muchas gracias!

Comment: De nada :), ahora publico una respuesta explicando el motivo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error `Cannot modify header information` de PHP suele producirse cuando se da salida a la información antes de modificar la cabecera con `header('Location: panel_de_control.php');`

En la **linea 4** de tu checklogin.php tienes un **espacio en blanco**, ese espacio está generando esa salida de información, si por ejemplo, pusieses un `echo("Hola")`, antes de tu `header()`posiblemente resultaría en el mismo error.

La solución es eliminar `?>` en la linea 3 y `<?php` en la linea 5, dejando solo los `<?php ... ?>` al principio y al final.